# Why am I getting "Thread was being aborted" in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, exception

I am not sure why this happens and I never explicitly abort threads, so it's a bit of a surprise. But I log Exceptions and I am seeing:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException - Thread was being aborted.

It appears to happen in a call to `System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne`. I am not sure how far this Exception goes. I don't think my threads ever terminate, because I catch log and swallow the error.

Why am I getting these errors? Perhaps it's when I am forcefully terminating my server or asking it to reboot? If it isn't then what might be causing them?

Comment: Can you show the code you have in Application_Start?

Comment: @rick: I dont know what you expect to find but here is a snippet. `var obj1=new MyServiceObject(); srv1 = new Thread(obj1.Queue); ... srv1.Start()`. Note that obj1 isnt inside a using block so it isnt disposed of prematurely. Its just a plain thread i spawn on startup

Comment: My guess is that your srv1 variable is losing scope and killing the thread. You'll need to wait on it to complete, or change the scope to a higher level scope. (I realize that this answer is 10 years late; however, I thought someone else may see this.) I had a similar problem with logging in an asp.net application - I was trying to log in a separate thread and the thread kept dying. After I changed the scope of the variable it was assigned to, the garbage collector left it alone.

Answer (score 57):

ASP.NET spawns and kills worker processes all the time as needed.  Your thread may just be getting shut down by ASP.NET.

**Old Answer:**

Known issue: [PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629)

```
Response.Redirect ("bla.aspx", false);
```

or

```
try
{
    Response.Redirect("bla.aspx");
}
catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: hmm. Good answer +1 but thats not it. This is actually happening on threads i spawn (usually from Application_Start) and not on the main request path.

Answer (score 56):

Nope, `ThreadAbortException` is thrown by a simple [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx)

Comment: hmm. Good answer +1 but thats not it. This is actually happening on threads i spawn (usually from Application_Start) and not on the main request path.

Comment: That's only one way to get a ThreadAbortException - you make it sound like that's the only way. E.g. could also be a request took > 90 seconds so IIS killed it.

Answer (score 49):

If you spawn threads in `Application_Start`, they will still be executing in the application pool's `AppDomain`.

If an application is idle for some time (meaning that no requests are coming in), or certain other conditions are met, `ASP.NET` will recycle the entire `AppDomain`.

When that happens, any threads that you started from that `AppDomain`, including those from `Application_Start`, will be aborted.

Lots more on application pools and recycling in this question: [What exactly is Appdomain recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564/what-exactly-is-appdomain-recycling)

If you are trying to run a long-running process within `IIS/ASP.NET`, the short answer is usually "Don't".  That's what Windows Services are for.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what is happening. I have another question... Is Application_Start run again when the site becomes active again? It looks like it isnt (but i may have coded something wrong)

Comment: It isn't.  From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx "The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance."

Comment: I'm seeing this happen with very little idle time. Like, between back to back requests :/

Answer (score 23):

For a web service hosted in ASP.NET, the configuration property is executionTimeout:

```
<configuration> <system.web>

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />

</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Set this and the thread abort exception will go away :)

Comment: Found this to be the fix when doing asynchronous web calls.

Comment: "Set this and the thread abort exception will go away".. for a few minutes ;)

Comment: Yeah, why bother with all sorts of code changes when just one line in the web.config does it. Upvoted.

Comment: but the MSDN says about ExecutionTimeout:"This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the <compilation> element is set to false." I have debug=true but it still happens.

Answer (score 11):

This problem occurs in the `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer` methods, because both methods call `Response.End` internally.

The solution for this problem is as follows.

For `Server.Transfer`, use the `Server.Execute` method instead.

Answer (score 8):

This error can be caused by trying to end a response more than once. As other answers already mentioned, there are various methods that will end a response (like `Response.End`, or `Response.Redirect`). If you call more than one in a row, you'll get this error.

I came across this error when I tried to use `Response.End` after using `Response.TransmitFile` which seems to end the response too.

Comment: Odds are, doing anything with the response after it was ended could lead to this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I did a `Response.Redirect` after a successful login of the user.

I fixed it by doing a `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` instead.