# Can WaitHandle.WaitOne throw a ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-mobile, threadabortexception

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception of type ThreadAbortException occurred: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: ThreadAbortException 
at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext) 
at MyCode.ProcessEvents()
```

And I'm confused about how it could happen. I'm sure that I'm not aborting this particular thread, though my code could be aborting a different one (including the thread that sets the WaitHandle). This leads me to believe that either the framework is raising the exception or a threadabortexception for a different thread is bleeding out into this one somehow. Neither of which I thought were possible.

So, If I am not calling Thread.Abort() on this thread, how can it end up with a ThreadAbortException?

Comment: So what's your question. I can't get your point exactly. Is your question how can runtime throw exception in a thread waiting at `WaitOne`?

Comment: Have clarified the question: I was of the opinion that the only way for a thread to get this exception was if I call thread.abort on it. But I'm not, so i'm baffled how this stack trace is even possible

Comment: Could you post some repro with small sample program?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7629986/56778

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Unfortunately, I haven't repro'd the issue. The trace is from logs on a customer server and it happens quite rarely. In my googling, I did see mention of asp.net being able to abort threads but this is c# running on a windows mobile device so didn't think it applied.