# Using SignalR with RabbitMQ

Tags: iis, rabbitmq, signalr, application-pool

I am writing an application where messages about data changes through an API are published over a RabbitMQ message bus. The messages are consumed by a SignalR hub and pushed to subscribed clients.

Now I find messages in my Eventlog that start with:

> Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

I found SO questions and answers like:
[Why am i getting "Thread was being aborted" in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629986/why-am-i-getting-thread-was-being-aborted-in-asp-net)
and 
[What exactly is Appdomain recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564/what-exactly-is-appdomain-recycling)

But that raises the question, if applications running in an AppDomain in the application pool is recycled upon inactivity, how can SignalR maintain a connection to subscribed clients?
Why does it work for SignalR to run in an IIS app pool but not a RabbitMQ consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR client libraries provided by the SignalR might have a default behavior of **reconnecting once loosing connection** (the JS one definitely does).

So having an Pool Recycle would just make your client reconnect to your server, getting again messages as before interruption.

Comment: When reconnecting the client sends group membership to the server in groupsToken.

Comment: Updated accordingly