# While putting bin file, why it interrupts IIS service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

When I put the bin file (includes .dll) to the web server, it takes approximately 30-60 seconds (after the upload completed) to publish.  I think IIS debug it and until publishing, when I enter the web site, it gives error.

Are there any way for putting the bin file to web server without interruption.
(The project is coded with c#)

Comment: "The bin file"? What bin file? How are you uploading it? Does that 30-60second pause occur after the upload completes? Or is it perhaps the time taken to actually do the upload?

Comment: I am working on a project with asp.net, c#. After the upload completes, it will 30-60 seconds to be viewed.

Comment: I think you are right because in a day sometimes it gives error for a while. After 1-2 minutes, it is coming back.

Comment: This must be a massive duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is Appdomain recycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564/what-exactly-is-appdomain-recycling)

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide the details of the error?

By dropping a 'bin' file on the server I assume you mean a .dll in the 'bin' folder? It likely causes the application to recycle and recompile which takes time depending on the performance of your server.

Comment: Yes true, it includes .dll, are there any way doing this without interruption?

Comment: It sounds like your app is what microsoft calls "precompiled" and in this instance you can't avoid the interruption.  The alternative method of deployment is to not precompile your website and then you will be able to make changes to any of your code behind files and upload those files without the app. recycling.  Note:  If you modify the web.config or the Bin directory in either a precompile app or non precompiled app, it will cause IIS to recycle it.

Comment: @CheckRaise - if a DLL changes, ASP.NET WILL recompile UNLESS everything is precompiled. In either case, the app may need to recycle to get the new code running. It will try to finish up existing requests with the 'old' code but, especially if there are A LOT of recompiles, it may recycle.

Answer (score 0):

When you alter the content of the bin folder the web site restarts if you have a lot of uncompiled resources needed when you request the site after uploading this is going to take take. You can use the web deploy project from Visual studio and choose to precompile the project. When uploaded it's (more or less) available immediately